# jupyter nbconvert --to slides fails due to access permissions

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I'm trying to generate a slideshow for my notebook using `nbconvert`. Using windows, jupyter and python 3.

https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#convert-revealjs

I'm running the command in a command shell in admin mode:

```
jupyter nbconvert C:\files\notebook.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

The files\ directory contains a directory called `reveal.js`.

The following error is raised,

```
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook C:\files\notebook.ipynb to slides
[NbConvertApp] Writing 379320 bytes to C:\files\notebook.slides.html
[NbConvertApp] Serving local reveal.js
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-nbconvert-script.py", line 5, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
app.start()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 293, in start
self.convert_notebooks()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 457, in convert_notebooks
self.convert_single_notebook(notebook_filename)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 430, in convert_single_notebook
self.postprocess_single_notebook(write_results)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 402, in postprocess_single_notebook
self.postprocessor(write_results)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\postprocessors\base.py", line 28, in __call__
self.postprocess(input)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\postprocessors\serve.py", line 87, in postprocess
http_server.listen(self.port, address=self.ip)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 126, in listen
sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 194, in bind_sockets
sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Which indicates that the port is already in use locally- I believe it defaults to 8000. Is there a way to specify the port when running the nbcovert command? E.g. not 8000.

NB The file `notebook.slides.html` is being created, and I can manually serve it up with `http.server` on a different port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed change the port. Modify the command as follows:

```
jupyter nbconvert C:\files\notebook.ipynb --to slides --ServePostProcessor.port=8910 --post serve
```